# Capture group that captures an entire string minus a section that matches a pattern

Tags: regex

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I figured I'd ask anyways. What I need to do is effectively create a search/replace, but without using the regex s/pattern1/pattern2/ syntax as it is not directly exposed to me.

Is it possible to create a capture group that would take an image path, with the image size before the extension and remove the image size.

For instance convert `http://example.com/path/to/image/filename-200x200.jpg` to `http://example.com/path/to/image/filename.jpg` using only a capture group and no search/replace bits.

I'm asking as the software I'm working in does not currently have a search/replace functionality.

Comment: Do you have access to any of the code of the application, or are you using a search box on some kind of web app?

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat possible. There's no built-in capability for a match to be something other than a continuous segment of the source text, but you can work around that.

One approach you might consider is the use of non-capturing groups and concatenation. In regex, groups beginning with `?:` aren't captured as matches.

For example, given the regex `(A)(?:B)(C)` and the string `"ABC"`, the result would be:

```
1. "A"
2. "C"
```

In your case, then, you could capture around the part you want to ignore, then concatenate the parts you want.

Given the string you provided, `http://example.com/path/to/image/filename-200x200.jpg`, the regex `(.+)(?:-200x200)(.+)` returns:

```
1. "http://example.com/path/to/image/filename"
2. ".jpg"
```

You could then add the first and second capture groups to produce your intended result.